# jquery mouseover firing again when rolling over another div

Tags: jquery, mouseover

This is killing me! LOL

I tried everything, hover, mouseover, mouseenter...stop(true)

Why is this so hard?

I am just going to link you to the page, roll over the big picture, then place you mouse lower on the button - see how it fires twice?

I want that hole area to stop, until I leave my mouse from it.

http://www.lapiazzaonline.com/owen/index2.html

```
$(".smerrick").mouseover(function(){
        $(".ssmerrick")
            .animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"470px"}, 100);

            $(".melville").fadeTo(600, 0.2);
            $(".plainview").fadeTo(600, 0.2);
    });
    $(".smerrick").mouseout(function(){
        $(".ssmerrick")
            .animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"510px"}, 100);

            $(".melville").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $(".plainview").fadeTo(0, 1);
    });
```

I will post here the code, just in case fiddle doesn't keep the code for future reference.
Thanks for all the help, this one seems to work - however I didnt try anikr beacuse this seems fine.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".views strong").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('em').animate({'bottom':'0px'}, 200).end().closest('div').siblings().fadeTo(600, .2);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('em').animate({'bottom':'-30px'}, 200).end().closest('div').siblings().fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="plainview views" style="opacity: 1; ">
    <div class="logo-plainview"></div>
    <a href="#"><strong><em>Plainview</em></strong></a>
    <p>1137 Old Country Road • Plainview, New York 11803</p>
    <p class="number">(516) 938-0800</p>
</div>



<div class="merrick views" style="opacity: 1; ">
    <div class="logo-merrick"></div>
    <a href="#"><strong><em>Merrick</em></strong></a>
    <p>2191 Merrick Road • Merrick, New York 11566</p>
    <p class="number">(516) 546-2500</p>            
</div>
```

CSS

```
.plainview {
    width:316px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.logo-plainview {
    background:url(http://www.lapiazzaonline.com/owen/images/logo-plainview.png) no-repeat;
    height:124px;
    width:289px;
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    left:15px;
}
.plainview strong {
    background:url(http://www.lapiazzaonline.com/owen/images/plainview.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:474px;
    width:316px;
    position:absolute;
    top:166px;
    left:0;
    display: block;
}
.plainview strong em {
    background:url(http://www.lapiazzaonline.com/owen/images/s-plainview.png) no-repeat;
    height:164px;
    width:233px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    left:43px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.plainview p{
    width:316px;
    position:absolute;
    top:675px;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:#CCC;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: can u  post your html code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked your site a lot and fiddled with it a bit. :) [Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/Ed8Jh/1/)

As you can see I grouped lots of things together. Changed CSS a little bit and there is the final result.

What was your problem? because `smerrick` not contains `ssmerrick` when you mouse over `ssmerrick` it automatically gets out of `smerrick` and triggers `mouseout` function. Basicly I put `ssmerrick` inside `smerrick` and changed CSS accordingly.

Comment: Pretty cool, jquery ninja! there was a line of code at the bottom `code`<embed id="Siber_embed1" type="application/rf-np-plugin" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: fixed; display: block; ">`code` -- i didnt know what it was refering too, maybe fiddle just places it in there

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".smerrick").mouseover(function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"470px"}, 100);

            $(".melville").fadeTo(600, 0.2);
            $(".plainview").fadeTo(600, 0.2);
    });
    $(".smerrick").mouseout(function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"510px"}, 100);

            $(".melville").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $(".plainview").fadeTo(0, 1);
    });         
//and do accordingly
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No that doesnt work... I uploaded to the website so you can see ( roll over the middle graphic )

Answer (score 0):

I saw your HTML Code. The event is fired twice only in the case when you hover on the small image and then move out. In this case, the larger image(on which the event is applied) is hovered twice hence the two animations.

The HTML can be modified from

```
<a href="#">
     <div class="smerrick"></div>
     <div class="ssmerrick"></div>
</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#">
     <div class="smerrick"></div>
     <div class="ssmerrick" ></div>
     <div class="smerrick2"></div>
</a>
```

You can have a overlay  for all the three stores with css equivalent to

```
.smerrick2 {
    left: 0;
    height : 474px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 166px;
    width: 316px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

And bind the mouse over and mouse out on that overlay div. The idea is when you move out from small image you again hover on the bigger one, hence the event fires twice. So this way it can be stopped.

```
$(".smerrick2").unbind('mouseover').bind('mouseover', function(){

        $(".ssmerrick").animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"470px"}, 100);
        $(".melville").fadeTo(600, 0.2);
        $(".plainview").fadeTo(600, 0.2);

}).unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', function(){

        $(".ssmerrick").animate({bottom:"14px"}, 200).animate({top:"510px"}, 100);
        $(".melville").fadeTo(0, 1);
        $(".plainview").fadeTo(0, 1);

});
```

See if this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but the first post worked... it seems more optimized also